# How to display android sms inbox

Tags: android, sms

```
Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.msg,"message received",System.currentTimeMillis());
                    PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW), 0);
```

I am using broadcast receiver to notify for incoming message. i am able to display my own notification in notification bar when message is received. i need when user clicks it it go to Inbox or currently received message.

```
PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, People.CONTENT_URI), 0);
//          notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Time has been Reset", "Click on me to view Contacts", myIntent);
```

like here when user click it goes to contacts in android. so what i pass in intent that when user clicks it goes to inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from http://www.anddev.org/open_sms_activity-t6375.html:

```
        String SMS_MIME_TYPE = "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms";

        Intent defineIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);                

        defineIntent.setType(SMS_MIME_TYPE);                

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , defineIntent, 0);
```

Comment: This technique is undocumented, unsupported, may not work on some current Android devices, may not work on future Android devices, and is not recommended.

Comment: oh. just checked in my code working right now let see if another option is there.