# How to open and show phone's message inbox programmatically..?

Tags: android, android-activity, sms

When we click on messages we are showed with the inbox.

I want to show the same window when i clicked on my application's button.

So, I want to start message inbox activity.

How to achieve this...?

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. works perfectly..!

```
public void openInbox() {
String application_name = "com.android.mms";
try {
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
List<ResolveInfo> resolveinfo_list = this.getPackageManager()
.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

for (ResolveInfo info : resolveinfo_list) {
if (info.activityInfo.packageName
.equalsIgnoreCase(application_name)) {
launchComponent(info.activityInfo.packageName,
info.activityInfo.name);
break;
}
}
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
Toast.makeText(
this.getApplicationContext(),
"There was a problem loading the application: "
+ application_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

private void launchComponent(String packageName, String name) {
Intent launch_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
launch_intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
launch_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));
launch_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivity(launch_intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String SMS_MIME_TYPE = "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms";

        Intent defineIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);                

        defineIntent.setType(SMS_MIME_TYPE);                

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , defineIntent, 0);
```

Not sure whether it works or not

Comment: yea, i wasnt sure. Found it some where in old questions, saved it in my documents for future purpose.

Comment: yea this was the question where i got it from:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608055/how-to-display-android-sms-inbox

Comment: It is working for me, I'm using this in notifications. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

SMS content provider will give you the all sms related data . the Screen you are talking about is implemented by manufacturer using that data . so  you have two choices to achieve this :

1) Use cursor returned by related content provider and create your own screen with desired look and feel .

2) get Information about package name of message screen for diffrent manufacures (like suppose samsung have com.samsung.smsscreeen ) and lauch intent for this class name . write case statements for devices you want to add.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Can you please share a code that can open only samsung sms screen.

Answer (score 0):

I extended srinivasa's solution above to get the package name of the default SMS app currently being used on the device:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        application_name = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this);
    }
```

I found this worked well across Samsung and Nokia devices which both use a different app for SMS out of the box.