# How to add auto fill suggestion for otp

Tags: android, message, autofill, one-time-password

I've seen in some app(don't remember name) where under textbox, a small pop-up is shown saying

> Auto fill code from messages

I want to add a similar functionality to my app. As suggested in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/autofill/HintConstants#AUTOFILL_HINT_SMS_OTP) add auto fill hints and set autofill importance to achieve this behaviour. i've tried both but none worked.
I've tried followings

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_login"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/x60"
        android:id="@+id/pin"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="PIN"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/x16"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:id="@+id/et_pin"
            android:importantForAutofill="yes"
            android:autofillHints=".AUTOFILL_HINT_SMS_OTP"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_pin"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I want to have get this type of thing in my app

[image]

Comment: If you have received OTP then why are you suggesting user to add the OTP. I mean instead of asking user to set the otp just set the otp automatically.

Comment: Application can't fetch otp auto from user messages, i want some mechanism for this. I'm not using firebase. SMS is sent from my server using twillio. and Android is not allowing reading users sms only to verify otp.

Comment: is Twillio providing some on success or receive listeners(call backs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Add the following to edittext in xml:

```
 android:autofillHints="smsOTPCode"
 android:importantForAutofill="yes"
```

2.Enable the autofill service by navigating to **Settings > Google > Autofill > Sms verification codes > Autofill service**.

**Note**: This solution will work on android 8 and above.

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways to handle this

1. SMS read Permission(not recommended)

you can create a popup and give permission when the user touch it.

2. SMS retriever API( recommended)

you can set SMS retriever API ([look at this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview))
and create a popup when user touch it then fill the text view

Comment: The pop-up in above shared image is any how displayed by android OS, i want to know the trick behind it

Comment: if you mean the icon of the current messaging applications, you can get it from package manager and filter them by mime_type like "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms" and find the currently active messaging application. look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567957/how-to-get-running-applications-icon-on-android-programmatically

Comment: look at this link bro,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711940/how-to-open-and-show-phones-message-inbox-programmatically

Comment: I think you can get your answer by merging code from two links above and also Sms retiver API

Comment: Yes, i found one more accurate ways, merging sms retiver api and twillio to achieve required behaviour. This approach will not require SMS read permission. https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/app-verification#verify-android-phone-numbers-with-twilio

Comment: is something similar available for accessing otp from gmail ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable autofill in the Android settings?

- First select an autofill service, e.g. Google.
- Settings -> Google -> Autofill -> SMS Verification codes -> Switch to enabled

See: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-sms-verification-code-autofill-in-android/

Answer (score -2):

After a lot of searches and losing hope in doing it, I found that it was very simple just you set it important for autofill

Edit text code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/otp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:autofillHints="smsOTPCode"
    android:importantForAutofill="yes"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/status" />
```

and I did set the autofill hint in code also

```
lateinit var statusView: TextView
lateinit var otpView: TextView
lateinit var acceptView: RadioButton
lateinit var rejectView: RadioButton
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    statusView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.status)
    otpView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.otp)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        otpView.setAutofillHints(AUTOFILL_HINT_SMS_OTP)
    }
    acceptView = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.accept)
    rejectView = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.reject)
    startListeningForSms(this,this)
    Log.e(javaClass.simpleName, AppSignatureHelper(this).appSignatures.toString())
}
fun startListeningSms(
    context: Context,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner
) {
    val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(context)

    // Starts SmsRetriever, which waits for ONE matching SMS message until timeout
    // (5 minutes). The matching SMS message will be sent via a Broadcast Intent with
    // action SmsRetriever#SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.
    val task: Task<Void> = client.startSmsRetriever()

    // Listen for success/failure of the start Task. If in a background thread, this
    // can be made blocking using Tasks.await(task, [timeout]);
    task.addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<Void?> {
        // Successfully started retriever, expect broadcast intent
    })

    task.addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener {
        // Failed to start retriever, inspect Exception for more details
    })
}
```

I'm not sharing the whole activity code, I'm just sharing code related to autofill.[image]

AppSignatureHelper can be found here : https://github.com/googlearchive/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java

and autofill library can be added in dependancy

```
implementation "androidx.autofill:autofill:1.1.0"
```

Comment: This code is incomplete:
what is startListeningForSms function?
what is AUTOFILL_HINT_SMS_OTP constant?

Comment: AUTOFILL_HINT_SMS_OTP is found in auofill library

    implementation "androidx.autofill:autofill:1.1.0"

Answer (score -2):

Solution from Burak Dizlek does not work for me.

Instead - and I tested it sussecfully - use Android SMS Retriever here https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

With the SMS Retriever API, you can perform SMS-based user verification in your Android app automatically, without requiring the user to manually type verification codes, and without requiring any extra app permissions

CODING

1. Get you app hash using keytool or Helper, see https://github.com/shishirthedev/sms-verification-api-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/shishirthedev/smsretriverapi/AppSignatureHashHelper.kt
2. Start SmsRetrieverClient

   ```
   SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(context);
   Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever()
   ```
3. Create BroadCast Receiver awaiting for SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION

   ```
   public class MySMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");
    if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);
        switch(status.getStatusCode()) {
            case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                // Get SMS message contents
                String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
           case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT: 
                // handle timeout
   ```
4. Register this BR in Activity onResume

   ```
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION);
    mySMSBroadcastReceiver = new MySMSBroadcastReceiver();

    protected void onResume() {  
       super.onResume();
       registerReceiver(mySMSBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter, RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
     }
   ```

THEN
once you send SMS (you dont need server) your app will recieves it within BR and you can work with it

```
onOTPReceived: Your code is: 123456                                                                                                
504w8vEgbb8
```